# Symmetric Positive Definite Matrices and Norms?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

Suppose $A \in \mathbf{R}^{n\times n}$ is symmetric positive definite. Show that $||x||_A = \sqrt{x^TAx}$ defines a norm for the vector $x$.

Why are the first two properties of norms obvious? That is, why can:

- $||x||_A \geq 0, \forall \space x; ||x||_A = 0 \leftrightarrow x = 0$
- $||ax|| = |a|||x||, \quad \forall \space x$

be easily seen? I can prove the triangle property (property 3: not listed), but does the first property follow directly from the fact $A$ is symmetric positive definite? What about the second? Thanks!

Comment: What is your definition of positive-definite?

Comment: Yes the first property directly follows from the definition of a positive definite matrix. For the second, note that $\| ax\|_A = \sqrt{(ax)^T A (ax)} = \sqrt{a^2 (x^T A x)} = a \|x \|_A$.

Comment: @sudeep5221 you need to surround $a$ with absolute value bars, in RHS, (last expression on the right)

Comment: @Physor Yup, you're right. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Non-negativity:

$A\succ 0$ implies that $x^\top A x > 0$ for all $x\neq 0$, so $\lVert x\rVert_A > 0$. On the other hand $x^\top A x = 0 \iff x = 0$, so $\lVert x\rVert_A \geq 0$.

2. Triangle inequality:

Using Cauchy-Schwarz
$$
\lVert x + y \rVert_A^2 = \lVert x\rVert_A^2 + 2x^\top Ay + \lVert y\rVert_A^2\leq \lVert x\rVert_A^2 + 2\lVert x\rVert_A\lVert y\rVert_A + \lVert y\rVert_A^2 = (\lVert x\rVert_A + \lVert y\rVert_A)^2,
$$
which implies $\lVert x + y \rVert_A\leq \lVert x\rVert_A + \lVert y\rVert_A$.

3. Homogeneity:
   $$
   \lVert ax \rVert_A = \sqrt{(ax)^\top A(ax)} = \sqrt{a^2x^\top Ax} = \lvert a\rvert\sqrt{x^\top Ax} = \lvert a \rvert\lVert x \rVert_A
   $$

Answer (score 0):

Every positive definite symmetric matrix has a unique positive definite symmetric square root. That is, for your $A$ there exists a unique symmetric positive definite $S$ such that $A=S^2$. In particular
$$\|x\|_A^2=x^TAx=x^TSSx=(Sx)^TSx=\|Sx\|^2$$
so that $\|x\|_A=\|Sx\|$ and it is now straightforward to prove that this is norm.